# Read localized PDF file using Itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, hindi

I am trying to read PDF file using iTextSharp. The issue is when trying to read a PDF file other than English (Hindi or Arabic for example) it's not getting the correct words.

I am wondering, should I install the Hindi or Arabic font on my system or do I need to do something with encoding?

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
text.Append(currentText);
```

**Edit:**

Sample PDF as Image:

[image]

Extracted Text:

uxj ikfydk ifj"kn  fuokZpd ukekoyh& 2011
i`"B la[;k %
1 1 1 1& & & & ftys dk uke ftys dk uke ftys dk uke ftys dk uke % % % %
0701-ò¶âã£ûæ–
2 2 2 2& & & & fudk fudk fudk fudk; ; ; ; dk uke dk uke dk uke dk uke % % % % 
 1-¢âî™
3 3 3 3& & & & okMZ la okMZ la okMZ la okMZ la[ [ [ [; ; ; ;k o uke k o uke k o uke k o uke % % % %
1-¯â“¯â™®â£û¶âû §âîºâã®â£û¶âû Õô¯âû®â£û¶âû
4 4 4 4& & & & Hkkx la Hkkx la Hkkx la Hkkx la[ [ [ [; ; ; ;k k k k % % % %

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/10191879/231316

Comment: Sorry Chris, no help. I am trying to read Hindi PDF file.

Comment: Can you post a sample PDF? If not, can you at least post the raw bytes extracted, maybe the first 20 or so? Fonts should not matter in any way for text extraction, fonts are only used for rendering.

Comment: Hi Chris, Just edited the post with sample pdf as image attached and extracted text for some of the part

Comment: Hi Chris, Please comment on my response. I did find any solution for  my issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Do not use any kind of Encoding, because you do  not know what
>   encoding is the pdf file has.

.
I think it will work.

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
text=text+currentText;

///do what you want with text
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

If still it not working then you have to install specific font.

Comment: did you installed necessary font?

Comment: I am able to see the PDf with correct format. Event I am debugging the code and getting the text string which is not correct format. So I believe font is installed.

Comment: Not correct, it's garbage. Looks like "uxj ikfydk ifj"kn  fuokZpd ukekoyh& 2011
i`"B la[;k %
1 1 1 1& & & & ftys dk uke ftys dk uke ftys dk uke ftys dk uke % % % %"

Comment: facing similar  issue