# when I read a PDF doc using iTextSharp only get *?* character

Tags: c#, character-encoding, itext

I'm trying to read text in a PDF doc using itextsharp library. I have a problem with a particular doc that only returns *?* character. However with others doc I have not any problem.

¿What is the reason for that?

Here is my code

```
    private void readPDF()
    {
        string pdfTemplate = @"c:\\test2.pdf";

        // Título de formulario
        this.Text += " - " + pdfTemplate;

        String strText="";
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);

            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
                strText = strText + s;

            }
            reader.Close();

            textBox1.Text = strText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?? Thanks

Comment: can you extract text from that PDF in say Acrobat Reader using text tool select -> copy -> paste?

Comment: First, see my post here about how to work with strings http://stackoverflow.com/a/10191879/231316

Comment: What is the intent of this funny re-encoding line?

Comment: @mkl, that line has been copied and pasted everywhere and it makes me cry a little bit every time