# Itextsharp Pdf to Text extraction

Tags: pdf, itext

If i save a uploaded pdf file it throws a corrupted format msg.Thing is if i remove
below code
 string resumetext = ParsePdf(resumedoc.PostedFile.InputStream); 
        Pdf file is saved perfectly.I can open it.
if i add the above code Pdf file is saved as a corrupted format.

I can read the text perfectly in both conditions.Please help me to sort out the issue.

```
 string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUp.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (ext == ".pdf")
        {
    //resumedoc is input type='file' 
            string resumetext = ParsePdf(resumedoc.PostedFile.InputStream); 
            string Filename = "dddd" + ext;
            string FilePath =  "E:\\temp\\" + Filename;
            FileUp.PostedFile.SaveAs(FilePath);//Problem arises only here
            Response.Write("Uploaded");

}

public string ParsePdf(Stream inFileName)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inFileName);
    for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
    {
        try
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            //ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
            text.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            text.Append(currentText);
        }
        catch { }

    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Habe you gritted first calling `FileUp.PostedFile.SaveAs(FilePath)` and only thereafter `string resumetext = ParsePdf(resumedoc.PostedFile.InputStream)`?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but please see this post explaining why you should never use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));` http://stackoverflow.com/a/10191879/231316

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that by reading the stream you're moving the stream's current position and that's freaking out the `SaveAs()` which is expecting the position to be at zero. After parsing but before writing try:

```
FileUp.PostedFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```