# How to add eliminate new line character from a byte in c#

Tags: c#, utf-8, ascii

I have a code as mentioned below. I have a "inputText" variable which contains the string as well as some new line characters. Just assume my variable inputText contains something like "Test\nTest". So when I get final output I need to remove \n new line char from the string.

```
currentText =
        Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(
            Encoding.Default,
            Encoding.UTF8,
            Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputText)));
```

Comment: `currentText = currentText.Replace("\n", string.Empty);` ?

Comment: If in case the string contains "\\n" then it should not do anything.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as an iText question? The answer has nothing to do with iText!

Comment: This is a very common code snippet that is copied and pasted all over from an iText text extraction sample somewhere but it is wrong and it will break! [In .Net, once you have a string, **you have a string**, and it is Unicode, **always**.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10191879/231316)

Comment: @Bruno that weird conversion is often seen in iTextSharp text extraction samples. Not the official ones but others, copied on and on without someone asking why it's there.

Comment: To quote Mr. T: *I pity the fools who don't read the official documentation* ;-)

Comment: @Chris I went through the link. What would you suggest for my problem.

Comment: The code snippet in the question is wrong. Any fixing of mangled strings should be done *before* it becomes a string.

Comment: You can either fix the content at the byte level before it becomes a string or you can hack something together once you've got a string. However, the code you posted is pretty much guaranteed to break things and should either just be removed or replaced with just `currentText = inputText`. Don't think of .Net strings in terms of bytes, that's a mistake. You can _ask_ .Net to convert a string into a byte array using a certain encoding but that's a conversion. Without seeing your actual string we can't really help you.

Comment: Chris, I have a code like this `string outputText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, intPage + 1, strategy);` . How can I eliminate the new line char from the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always remove `'\n'`s from the `currentText` string using `Replace`, but if you would rather remove `'\n'` from the array of bytes coming into `Convert` method, before constructing a `string` object, you can filter it like this:

```
currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(
    Encoding.Default,
    Encoding.UTF8,
    Encoding.Default
        .GetBytes(inputText)
        .Where(b => b != '\n')
        .ToArray()
    )
);
```