# ITextSharp for arabic support

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have to read the content of a .pdf file, I am using ITextSharp.net,
I have three problems:

1- the Arabic terms are extracted in reverse order.( ex: احمد is extracted as دمحا) which is reversed ( in English: Ahmad is extracted as damha )
if my file contains both Arabic and English, How to extract each language with its correct direction.

2- sometimes the glyphs are no defined as characters, so they appear as symbols, how to add my own definition for glyphs?

3- Can I extract the text with its formattings, to convert to html and display the file in a web page as is?

Comment: If you can detect Arabic terms by iterating over the text you extract, you could use a string reversal algorithm on those sections.

Comment: Can you show a code sample to understand the problem in a clearer manner?

Comment: The code is itextsharp code..very long

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading pdf  content using iTextSharp in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185643/reading-pdf-content-using-itextsharp-in-c-sharp)